# IE conditional comment for specific version not working

Tags: internet-explorer

I want ie conditional comment for only ie7. Here is the following code i do it for ie7 only.

`<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<link href="css/ie7.css" rel="stylesheet">
<![endif]-->`

It works well on ie7 but the why the same css is working on ie8 and ie9. It should be only for ie7 right? 
Is there anything am missing with the code. If yes please suggest. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this-

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
  According to the conditional comment this is IE 7<br />
<![endif]-->
```

**Update-**

If it still continues, check if your site is being rendered in compatibility mode as it is  rendered as IE7

Comment: Its still conflicting in ie8 and ie9

Comment: Thanks it was being rendered in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link href="css/ie7.css" rel="stylesheet">
<![endif]-->
```

Look here for more details: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

What you are doing is including the CSS file for IE 7 and below (lte -> less than equal)

Comment: Thanks for replying but its still conflicting in ie 8 and ie 9. I don't want the same style in ie8 and ie9.

Comment: You have something else wrong then. This works. ou are probably including the same CSS file in some other location.

Comment: ok I think i got the mistake. I am using windows 7. When i make a browser mode of my internet explorer to 'Internet Explorer 9 Compact View' and keep changing document mode(ie7,ie8,ie9), conditional comments style is working on every version of ie. It is working if i make change on browser mode from 'ie compact view' to ie 7. Its working now. Thanks. (sorry for my broken english)